# XNA 4.0 - Alpha and Multiple Textures ... Messed Up

Tags: c#, xna, alpha, texture2d

I am trying to make some sort of sliding menu... In a circle images will slide down or up as the user will touch the icons and slide them (like modern phones or like the casino machines' fruits etc...)

I have a transparent circle, and lets say three icons... How do I blend them in such a way ?

Items:

http://i52.tinypic.com/rcn67s.jpg

Problem:

http://i52.tinypic.com/i77nrk.jpg

I can make them get drawn by spriteBatch one by one with order but how to blend them in that way ?

I am sorry I can feel that its something that might be easy but I am stuck..

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it... Here's how:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace StencilTest
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Texture2D star, cloud, shape;
        AlphaTestEffect alphaTestEffect;
        DepthStencilState stencilAlways;
        DepthStencilState stencilKeep;
        RenderTarget2D rt;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            graphics.PreferredDepthStencilFormat = DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8;

            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;

            IsMouseVisible = true;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }

        Texture2D grass;

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            star = Content.Load<Texture2D>("star1");
            cloud = Content.Load<Texture2D>("cloud1");
            shape = Content.Load<Texture2D>("shape");
            back = Content.Load<Texture2D>("back");
            grass = Content.Load<Texture2D>("grass1");

            Matrix projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, shape.Width, shape.Height, 0, 0, 1);
            Matrix halfPixelOffset = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0);

            alphaTestEffect = new AlphaTestEffect(GraphicsDevice);
            alphaTestEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
            alphaTestEffect.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3();
            alphaTestEffect.AlphaFunction = CompareFunction.Equal;
            alphaTestEffect.ReferenceAlpha = 0;
            alphaTestEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            alphaTestEffect.View = Matrix.Identity;
            alphaTestEffect.Projection = halfPixelOffset * projection;

            // set up stencil state to always replace stencil buffer with 1
            stencilAlways = new DepthStencilState();
            stencilAlways.StencilEnable = true;
            stencilAlways.StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Always;
            stencilAlways.StencilPass = StencilOperation.Replace;
            stencilAlways.ReferenceStencil = 1;
            stencilAlways.DepthBufferEnable = false;

            // set up stencil state to pass if the stencil value is 1
            stencilKeep = new DepthStencilState();
            stencilKeep.StencilEnable = true;
            stencilKeep.StencilFunction = CompareFunction.Equal;
            stencilKeep.StencilPass = StencilOperation.Keep;
            stencilKeep.ReferenceStencil = 1;
            stencilKeep.DepthBufferEnable = false;

            rt = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, shape.Width, shape.Height,
                                   false, SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.Depth24Stencil8,
                                   0, RenderTargetUsage.DiscardContents);
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
                this.Exit();

            // TODO: Add your update logic here

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        float angle = 0f;
        private Texture2D back;
        Vector2 pos = new Vector2(400, 300);
        float cloudscale = 0.25f;

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            // set up rendering to the active render target
            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(rt);

            // clear the render target to opaque black,
            // and initialize the stencil buffer with all zeroes
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target | ClearOptions.Stencil,
                                 new Color(0, 0, 0, 1), 0, 0);

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque,
                       null, stencilAlways, null, alphaTestEffect);

            spriteBatch.Draw(shape, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0f,
                             Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.End();

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend,
                  null, stencilKeep, null, null);

            //for (int i = 0; i < Math.Ceiling(800 / (cloud.Width * cloudscale)); i++)
            //    for (int j = 0; j < Math.Ceiling(600 / (cloud.Height * cloudscale)); j++)
            //        spriteBatch.Draw(cloud, Vector2.Zero + new Vector2(i * cloud.Width * cloudscale, j * cloud.Height * cloudscale), null, Color.White, 0f,
            //         Vector2.Zero, cloudscale, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.Draw(grass, new Vector2(rt.Width / 2, rt.Height / 2) + new Vector2(0f, -100f), null, Color.White, 0f,
         new Vector2(grass.Width / 2, grass.Height / 2), .85f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.Draw(cloud, new Vector2(rt.Width/2, rt.Height/2), null, Color.White, 0f,
                     new Vector2(cloud.Width / 2, cloud.Height / 2), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.Draw(star, new Vector2(rt.Width / 2, rt.Height / 2) + new Vector2(0f, 100f), null, Color.White, 0f,
         new Vector2(star.Width / 2, star.Height / 2), .85f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.End();

            GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

            spriteBatch.Begin();

            spriteBatch.Draw(back, Vector2.Zero, null, Color.White, 0f, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.Draw(rt, pos + new Vector2(50f * (float)Math.Cos(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle)), 50f * (float)Math.Sin(MathHelper.ToRadians(angle))), null, Color.White, 0f, new Vector2(rt.Width / 2, rt.Height / 2), 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

            spriteBatch.End();

            // TODO: Add your drawing code here

            angle +=0.5f;

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make the circle bigger so that nothing can be shown under it and place it on top?

Comment: This is by far the easiest solution. And if I may add: you could use a scissor rectangle (or change the viewport) to reduce the area of overdraw that you need to cover. However, a solution also exists that uses a sequence of `BlendState`s (or, alternately, `DepthStencilState`s) that will allow you to do arbitrary cut-outs as per the original question.

Comment: Using the stencil buffer is the most flexible solution. Shawn Hargreaves has a post with some nice simple code: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/05/17/transitions-part-three-stencil-swipes.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/05/17/transitions-part-three-stencil-swipes.aspx)

Comment: Dear Aranda / Andrew , thanks a lot for your kind help. I will focus on those now and put a solution here back as soon as I do can.

Comment: Sane - the "menu" should float around the screen in which many other things are going on :) therefore i can't just make the circle bigger.